# Extending an automorphism to an inner one

Tags: automorphisms, division-rings, outer-automorphisms

Let $D$ be a division ring. I have in mind the following result.

> **Theorem**. For every automorphism $f$ of $D$, there is a division ring $E$ extending $D$ such that $f$ extends to an inner automorphism of $E$.

**Q1.** Is the Theorem correct? Any reference?

**Q2.** If $f$ fixes the centre of $D$ pointwise, can $E$ be chosen so as to have the same centre as $D$?

Comment: Why doesn't Skolem-Noether work?

Comment: @WatsonLadd Don't you need finite dimensionality over the center for Skolem-Noether?  To the OP: any conditions on D?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, Skolem-Noether would apply if D was finite dimensional over its centre (in this case, take $E=D$ as $f$ is inner). What if it is not?

Comment: @Kimball I'm afraid not, no condition on $D$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Q1, you can form the skew polynomial ring $D[t;f]$ (i.e., the ring of polynomials in $t$ with coefficients from $D$, and multiplication satisfying $tr=f(r)t$ for $r\in D$). This is an Ore domain, and has a skew field of fractions $E$ consisting of formal fractions $rs^{-1}$ where $r,s\in D[t;f]$ and $s\neq0$. Then conjugation by $t$ induces the automorphism $f$ on $D$.

This is fairly classical, and you can find details in (for example) Chapter 2 of P.M. Cohn's book "Skew Fields: Theory of General Division Rings".

I don't know the answer to Q2, but if no power of $f$ is inner, then I'd guess (but haven't checked) that the construction above works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why not consider directly the division ring of Laurent series $D((t,f))$ ?

Comment: @Drike Yes, that's easier.

Comment: You are right about your last comment: if no power of $f$ is inner and $f$ fixes $Z(D)$ pointwise, then $D((t,f))$ has centre $Z(D)$.